# How to display json into gridview?

Tags: yii

A filed of tbl is storing the json code.

e.g

> {"aa":"test 1", "bb":"test 2", "cc": "test 3"}

I want to display those json into cgridview as column fields

e.g

```
id | name | aa     | bb     | cc
1  | n1   | test 1 | test 2 | test 3
2  | n2   | test 4 | test 5 | test 6
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

1.Use json_decode to convert the json object to php array.
2.Use CArrayDataProvider.
3.Then access the array element like $data[key].

Answer (score 0):

you must to iterate the json by echo function of jquery.

```
var table="";
var json={"xxxx"};
$.each(json,function(k,v){
   table+="<td>"+v.aa+"</td>";
});
```

$("xxx").append(table);